# Rails: warning: already initialized constant User::HABTM_Roles rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan, rolify

This issue i' m facing When trying to create a seeds.rb inorder to define roles with rolify gem in rails

Comment: it would be helpful to provide your code for User.rb.

Comment: user.rb:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  rolify :role_cname => 'Usertype'
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end

Comment: I think you have to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to enhance your knowledge on asking question in stackoverflow. For e.g, source code are to be placed in your question and not in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

On **line 2**, change this `rolify rolify: role_cname => 'Usertype'` to

> rolify :role_cname => 'Usertype'

You have two `rolify` on your **User.rb**, only one is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Observation:
As per Rails convention, the constants should contain all Uppercase characters. I see that you have used HABTM_Roles, which is violating the rule.

HABTM_Roles should be written as

```
HABTM_ROLES
```

Also please check for any duplicate declaration of the constant exists, as the error says already initialized constant.